Find non-null adjacent values in a table
I have this data:
select * into temp3
from (values
    ('306B', 'Erin, Fromans',1,'2024-06-03 00:00:00.000', NULL),
    ('306B', 'Erin, Fromans',2,NULL, '2024-07-12 00:00:00.000'),
    ('306B', 'Erin, Fromans',4,NULL, NULL),
    ('306B', 'Erin, Fromans',5,NULL, NULL),
    ('306B', 'Erin, Fromans',6,NULL, '2024-11-15 00:00:00.000'),
    ('0208A','Guerrazzi, Kiana',4,'2024-08-26 00:00:00.000', NULL),
    ('0208A','Guerrazzi, Kiana',5,NULL, NULL),
    ('0208A','Guerrazzi, Kiana',6,NULL, '2024-11-15 00:00:00.000'),
    ('108B', 'Obeid, Tarek',2,'2024-10-07 00:00:00.000',NULL),
    ('108B', 'Obeid, Tarek',3,NULL, '2024-11-15 00:00:00.000'),
    ('416A', 'Castellano, Isabella',1,'2024-06-03 00:00:00.000', NULL),
    ('416A', 'Castellano, Isabella',2,NULL, '2024-07-12 00:00:00.000'),
    ('416A', 'Castellano, Isabella',4,'2024-08-26 00:00:00.000', NULL),
    ('416A', 'Castellano, Isabella',5,NULL, NULL),
    ('416A', 'Castellano, Isabella',6,NULL, '2024-11-15 00:00:00.000')
) as c(apt,name,block,indate,outdate)

I'm trying to use this code:
select t.apt,t.name,t.block,
    case when t.indate is not null then t.indate else (
             select min(t1.indate) 
             from temp3 t1 
             where t1.apt = t.apt and t1.name=t.name 
        ) end indate,
    case when t.outdate is not null then t.outdate else (
            select max(t1.outdate)
            from temp3 t1 
            where t1.apt = t.apt and t1.name=t.name
        ) end outdate
from temp3 t
where block=5

But I can't get the indate and outdate values right.
For indate, if the value is null, instead of min() I need to look at the prior block that is populated (not null) with a matching apt and name. So if the block is 5, I want to check the indate value from row where block is 4 first, then 3, and so on.
Similarly, for outdate if the value is null instead of max() I want to check for next block where outdate is not null. So check for the matching block 6 first, then 7, etc.
Given the data above, my result should look like this:



apt
name
block
indate
outdate




306B
Erin, Fromans
5
2024-06-03 00:00:00.000
2024-11-15 00:00:00.000'


0208A
Guerrazzi, Kiana
5
2024-08-26 00:00:00.000
2024-11-15 00:00:00.000


416A
Castellano, Isabella
5
2024-08-26 00:00:00.000
2024-11-15 00:00:00.000



How can I do this?

Make it easy to help you - simplify!

Failing to format your code in a reasonable way shows disrespect to those who might help you. You will have better results making the minimal effort to use decent indentation before submitted the question.

Oh, and what kind of database are you using? That can make a big difference. For example, are windowing functions available? That could be night/day for performance here.


Subqueries select nearest lower/higher block where indate/outdate is not NULL.
ORDER BY t1.block DESC so lower/higher block is selected first.
LIMIT 1 or TOP 1 (SQL Server) only the top result.

SELECT t.apt, t.emplid, t.ay, t.name, t.block, t.site,
  COALESCE(
    t.indate,
    (  SELECT t1.indate FROM temp3 t1 WHERE t1.apt = t.apt AND t1.name = t.name AND t1.ay = t.ay AND t1.site = t.site AND t1.block < t.block AND t1.indate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY t1.block DESC LIMIT 1 )
  ) AS indate,
  COALESCE(
    t.outdate,
    (  SELECT t2.outdate FROM temp3 t2 WHERE t2.apt = t.apt AND t2.name = t.name AND t2.ay = t.ay AND t2.site = t.site AND t2.block > t.block AND t2.outdate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY t2.block ASC LIMIT 1 )
  ) AS outdate
FROM temp3 t
WHERE t.block = 5 AND t.ay = '24-25'

will give the below output:



apt
emplid
ay
name
block
site
indate
outdate




306B
123456
24-25
Erin, Fromans
5
City
2024-08-26 00:00:000
2024-11-15 00:00:000


0208A
321654
24-25
Guerrazzi, Kiana
5
Ocala
2024-08-26 00:00:000
2024-11-15 00:00:000


416A
4580487
24-25
Castellano, Isabella
5
City
2024-08-26 00:00:000
2024-11-15 00:00:000




i couldn't run it, error is 'Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.' and 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.' also is that work for block4 and block 6?
'

@ayla that's what you get for not telling us what kind of database you have. This will work for MySQL (but will still be MUCH slower than SQL Server's windowing function option)

Try this. It uses window functions rather than joins and should perform way better:
;with neighbors as (
    select apt, name, block
        , coalesce(indate, lag(indate) ignore nulls over (partition by apt, name order by cast(block as integer))) as indate
        , coalesce(outdate, lead(outdate) ignore nulls over (partition by apt, name order by cast(block as integer))) as outdate
    from temp3
)
select * 
from neighbors 
where block = '5'

See it work here (db<>fiddle was down):

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=3eb916f7-0c14-4ac7-8e7c-363ee9aab0ef


If you're not able to use the IGNORE NULLS feature, which is new to SQL Server 2022, we can try using the correlated sub-queries option below. My first instinct was to use an APPLY lateral join, but then I realized I was only taking one value, so this would be similar and easier to understand:
select t.apt,t.name,t.block,
    coalesce(indate, (
           SELECT TOP 1 indate 
           FROM temp3 tIn
           WHERE tIn.apt = t.apt and tIn.name = t.name
               AND tIn.indate IS NOT NULL
               AND tIn.block < t.block
           ORDER BY tIn.block DESC
      )) indate,
    coalesce(outdate, (
           SELECT TOP 1 outdate 
           FROM temp3 tOut
           WHERE tOut.apt = t.apt and tOut.name = t.name
               AND tOut.outdate IS NOT NULL
               AND tOut.block > t.block
           ORDER BY tOut.block           
       )) outdate
from temp3 t
where block=5

See it here:

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=33b23a25-3d70-428f-b56a-6c790b810253

Again: this will be so much slower than the first option. It's running two separate subqueries for each main result (O(N²)), where the first option does it all in two linear passes through the data (O(N)). This is also a lot more complicated and more code.

block is already an integer, there's no need to cast it.

Thank you, it works for block=5. but doesn't pull all data when block=6 or 4. I need if indate is null for block=5, need to check block=4, if that is null too then check block=3 and so on

@ayla Oh, forgot to add the ignore nulls directive {face slap}

Okay, fixed now, including a sample data change where one of the 4 blocks also has no indate

If there's some issue keeping this from working, the next thing I'd try is an APPLY, but I'm not even sure what kind of database you're using

Yes, 'ignore nulls' doesn't work 'The function 'lag' must have an OVER clause.'  using SQL server. where to add apply?

@ayla Click the link. It runs just fine on the test data at sql-fiddle using sql server. Again: helpful to know what database you're using exactly, including which version.

Hmm... did some digging. The IGNORE NULLS option is new for SQL Server 2022. If you're using an older sql server, we'll need something different. But ideally keep this in mind, as this is (easily) the fastest way to do this.
